# Angular.js expression: output transformed object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have data like this:

```
var user = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  property: 'value',
  ranks: [
    {name: 'One', property: 'value'},
    {name: 'Two', property: 'value'}
  ]
}
```

I want to output somewhere in the page all user's rank names divided by commas, like this:

```
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>One, Two</td>
```

How to do this?

Pure javascript isn't working:

```
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td>{{user.ranks.map(function(r) { return r.name }).join(', ')}}</td>
```

I think here should be an Angular filter or something, but can't find anything.

Comment: Are there multiple users, or just one user?

Comment: Sure there will be multiple users, but I want to do this with each user separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write JS like that in your templates. The angular way would be to use a filter:

```
app.filter("usersFilter" , function () {
        return function(user) {
           return user.ranks.map(function(r) { return r.name }).join(', ');
        }
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<td>{{ user | usersFilter}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it so:

1. Wrote distinct `map` and `join` filters with parameters:

   ```
   app.filter("map", function() {
     return function(collection, attribute) {
       return collection.map(function(object) {
         var attr = object[attribute];
         return (typeof attr === "function") ? attr() : attr;
       });
     }
   });

   app.filter("join", function() {
     return function(collection, separator) {
       return collection.join(separator);
     }
   });
   ```
2. And then in template

   ```
   <td>{{user.ranks | map:'name' | join:', ' }}</td>
   ```

And now it works in a way I wanted.